Trying to import and use a method from different project in a multi-project visual studio solution
I thought this would be really easy to do using just a project reference, but I believe I am missing a step. I am very unfamiliar with working with multi-project solutions and appreciate any help!
I am upgrading a huge solution file to .net 8 from .net framework 4.8, and I am trying to fix this method to use it at multiple places throughout the solution:
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;
using P1S.Common.Extensions;
using P1S.Common.Interfaces;
using ConfigurationManager = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;
using IConfigurationProvider = P1S.Common.Interfaces.IConfigurationProvider;

namespace SepsisServer.Infrastructure.Configuration
{
    public class ConfigurationProvider : IConfigurationProvider, ICustomNameConfigurationProvider
    {
        public string Get(string settingKey)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            IConfiguration config = builder.Build();


            return config[settingKey];
            //return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
        }

One place I am trying to use it is here:
So I am importing the namespace with a using statement, which stays gray and Get is highlisted red, stating that Get does not exist in current context


using SepsisServer.Infrastructure.Configuration;
...
public TestEnvironment()
{
   //irrelevant code removed for simplicity
           IdentifiConnectionString = Get(Constants.Environment.IdentifiConnectionString);

}



I've added the reference to the correct project already, but that doesnt seem to change anything. How can I help visual studio find the correct method?

Get is an instance method of the class ConfigurationProvider. To use it you need an instance of the class ConfigurationProvider. Just writing Get doesn't help the compiler to find the method between your projects

I prefer to share source code between my own separate projects using file linking in a .csproj file.  There is only one copy of the source for any given class, so this is not copy & paste of source.  Yes, a compiled version of the code is duplicated between projects, but there's no .dll managment and no runtime overhead with this, and resulting executables are fully stand alone.

@Steve, ok! That makes sense! I am not sure how to do that- do you have any references I can look at? Thanks so much

@ErikEidt gotcha! How do you implemenet this, its not add exisiting item, is it?

@ErikEidt got it.  But even when I link the file, visual studio still cannot find the method just by the method name. Would I also need a class instance in that case?

No, you have to manually edit the .csproj file.

I have found the answer and will try to describe the issue as best I am able:
The reason visual studio could not find my method was because of issues between static / non-static classes. In order to use the method Get in Configuration Provider I had to create an instance of a class and use that as shown, what @Steve had mentioned in the comment,
these are the lines that make fix the problem from the file I was working in.


private static IConfigurationService configurationService;
...

 var configurationProvider = new ConfigurationProvider();
configurationService = new ConfigurationService(configurationProvider); 
...

ParseOrDefault(configurationProvider.Get(Constants.Environment.UpdateConnectionStringsForLocalEnvironment));




To add a reference to another project in your current project,You need to right-click on your project in the solution explorer and select "Add Reference" and then choose the project you want to reference in your solution.
If the answer does not work you may try to share more details about your projects.

hey yeah as I mentioned I already added the reference, so I'm not sure why it cannot find it.

I think maybe I need an instance of ConfigurationProvider, do you know how I ca do that?
